# 'yolo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, vscode, anaconda, yolo

Estoy replicando de notebook de google colab el cual funciona correctamente a Anaconda y VSCode, tengo mi enviroment instale **pip install tqdm**, **pip install ultralytics**, tengo en la misma carpeta el **yolov8s.pt**, **dataset.yaml** pero aun así, cuando ejecuto la linea

`!yolo task=detect mode=predict model=D:/ProyectosVisualCode/DetectPlacas/training_results/placas/weights/best.pt conf=0.77 source=D:/ProyectosVisualCode/DetectPlacastest_images`

me sale el error: **'yolo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

---

He cambiado a esto:

`!yolo task=detect mode=predict model=../DetectPlacas/training_results/placas/weights/best.pt conf=0.77 source=../DetectPlacas/test_images`

Pero sigue el mismo error

Comment: Con lo que cuentas sólo puedo decirte que al entorno donde ejecutas el notebook le falta el comando `yolo`. Lo más seguro es que lo hayas instalado en otro entorno. Prueba a ejecutar `pip list` o `conda list` para comprobar que tienes `ultralytics` instalado donde ejecutas el notebook.